# I have to click the button twice to get states to render correctly in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with React and I have a button that is suppose to set a state

```
<button class="button" onClick={this.setRecommendations}>
            Log Into Spotify
</button>
```

This calls the fucntion

```
setRecommendations(){
    recommendations().then(recs => {
      this.setState({recommendations: recs});
    });
  }
```

which updates this state `recommendations: [],` so when I click the button I wait a while, and nothing happens, but sure enough no matter how long I wait the moment I click the button again, results begin to display.

I know that setState is async but this code mimics an similar function that displayed results more instantaneously with just one click, is there anything I can do to make it work with one click?

*******update with more code*******

This is my app

```
  class App extends React.Component {
  //constructor
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      searchResults: [],
      recommendations: [],
      playlistName: 'New Playlist',
      playlistTracks: [],
      topAlbums: ["Cats", "Wicked", "Heathers", "Charli", "Little Mermaind"],
      album_count: [10, 20, 25, 30, 35],
      topArtist: ["Dua Lipa", "Sierra Boggess", "Barrett Wilbert Reed", "Charli XCX", "Jessica Klean"],
      artist_count: [5, 10, 25, 35, 55],
      topGenre: ["classical", "broadway", "pop", "punk", "hip-hop"],
      genre_count: [50, 25, 5, 13, 7],
      popRange: ["0-20", "21-40", "41-60", "61-80", "81-100"],
      pop_count: [20, 40, 60, 40, 20]
    };
    this.search = this.search.bind(this);
    this.setRecommendations = this.setRecommendations.bind(this);
    this.addTrack = this.addTrack.bind(this);
    this.removeTrack = this.removeTrack.bind(this);
    this.updatePlaylistName = this.updatePlaylistName.bind(this);
    this.savePlaylist = this.savePlaylist.bind(this);
  }

  search(term) {
    Spotify.search(term).then(searchResults => {
      this.setState({searchResults: searchResults});
    });
  }

  setRecommendations(){
    recommendations().then(recs => {
      this.setState({recommendations: recs});
    });
  }

  //addTracks
  addTrack(track) {
    let tracks = this.state.playlistTracks;
    if (tracks.find(savedTrack => savedTrack.id === track.id)) {
      return;
    }

    tracks.push(track);
    this.setState({playlistTracks: tracks});
  }

  //removeTracks
  removeTrack(track) {
    let tracks = this.state.playlistTracks;
    tracks = tracks.filter(currentTrack => currentTrack.id !== track.id);

    this.setState({playlistTracks: tracks});
  }

  //updatePlaylistName
  updatePlaylistName(name) {
    this.setState({playlistName: name});
  }

  //savePlaylist
  savePlaylist() {
    const trackUris = this.state.playlistTracks.map(track => track.uri);
    Spotify.savePlaylist(this.state.playlistName, trackUris).then(() => {
      this.setState({
        playlistName: 'New Playlist',
        playlistTracks: []
      });
    });
  }

  //This what we will see
  render() {
    //this.recommendations()
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Spotify Recommendations</h1>
        <div className="App">
          <button class="button" onClick={this.setRecommendations}>
            Log Into Spotify
          </button>
          <Graphs data={this.state.album_count} margin={this.state.topAlbums} />
          <div className="Graphs">
            <Graphs data={this.state.artist_count} margin={this.state.topArtist} />
          </div>
          <p> below are some recommendations based on your listening history </p>
          <div className="App-playlist">
            <RecommendationResults recommendationResults={this.state.recommendations}
                           onAdd={this.addTrack} />

            <Playlist playlistName={this.state.playlistName}
                      playlistTracks={this.state.playlistTracks}
                      onNameChange={this.updatePlaylistName}
                      onRemove={this.removeTrack}
                      onSave={this.savePlaylist} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

After clicking the button it displays recommendations

```
<RecommendationResults recommendationResults={this.state.recommendations}
                           onAdd={this.addTrack} />
```

which calls this component

```
class RecommendationResults extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="RecommendationResults">
        <h2>Recommendations</h2>
        <TrackList tracks={this.props.recommendationResults} onAdd={this.props.onAdd} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Which calls another component

```
class TrackList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="TrackList">
        {
          this.props.tracks.map(track => {
            return <Track track={track}
                          key={track.id}
                          onAdd={this.props.onAdd}
                          isRemoval={this.props.isRemoval}
                          onRemove={this.props.onRemove} />
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the function setRecommendations calls

```
//get recommendations based off song history
export async function recommendations(){
  const unique = await findUnique();
  const recommendations = [];
  for(var index = 0; index < unique.length; index++){
    var trackURI = (unique[index].uri).slice(14, (unique[index].uri).length);
    var rec = await Spotify.recommendations(trackURI, unique[index].pop);
    for(var i=0; i<rec.length; i++){
      recommendations.push(rec[i]);
    }
  }
  const uniqueRec = getUnique(recommendations);
  return await uniqueRec;
}
```

This function is the issue, nothing is returned from the else clause, thus if it is the first time it is called nothing will be returned until the second time.

```
//getAccessToken
  getAccessToken() {
    if (accessToken) {
      return accessToken;
    }
    const accessTokenMatch = window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/);
    const expiresInMatch = window.location.href.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/);
    if (accessTokenMatch && expiresInMatch) {
      accessToken = accessTokenMatch[1];
      const expiresIn = Number(expiresInMatch[1]);
      window.setTimeout(() => accessToken = '', expiresIn * 1000);
      window.history.pushState('Access Token', null, '/'); // This clears the parameters, allowing us to grab a new access token when it expires.
      return accessToken;
    } else {
      const accessUrl = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=token&scope=${scopes.join("%20")}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`;
      window.location = accessUrl;
    }
  },
```

Comment: Add some more context on how `state` is used in the UI. There is nothing inherently fishy about your `setRecommendations()` function.

Comment: you should add all the code you are using in your component, it will be easier to know whats wrong

Comment: I added more code, let me know if there's anything else you want to see. I will admit my function that setRecommendations is calling is kind of lengthy and could take a while, but it is so strange that I click login, and then login and wait and no matter how long I wait nothing shows until the second click.

Comment: Rather than using bind your can change your method declaration to `search = (term) => { ... }`. This attaches the method to the instance instead of the prototype, and has the same effect as binding in the constructor.

Comment: Just to be clear, I could, maybe should, do this for all functions? Because search is a leftover function that I don't really use anymore, that I forgot to delete.

Comment: Well no, you should only do this when you need effect of the `this` binding in the constructor. In other cases it's better to use the regular syntax to keep the method attached to the prototype so that the same function can be reused for every instance of the class.

Comment: Also, have you considered using a linter for your code? I like eslint. I'd also recommend prettier, which has some nice IDE integrations (I use vscode). I'd also highly recommend TypeScript - I personally don't write vanilla JavaScript anymore, and according to the 2019 State of JavaScript it's one of the hottest languages to learn.

Comment: I can tell you exactly what is wrong now. The foundation for this was a codecademy project that is purely client side 100% in React and JavaScript. Whatever they are doing in getAccessToken must be done first. Before anything requiring an Access Token can be done. You may see in the else clause of the function nothing is done after `window.location=[the url]` thus if a function calls getAccessToken, if it is the first time they will not receive anything, it won't be until the second time it is called that a token will be returned. Now if you have suggestions for that let me know

Comment: Just a little note here, make sure to use `className` and not `class`, as `class` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript. So instead of `<button class="button">` it should be `<button className="button">`

Comment: Another note, to avoid `props drilling` and simplify the code, you can use the Context API or React Redux. So that you can provide `tracks` to `Tracklist` directly, without providing them as prop to `RecommendationResults` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem being that `getAccessToken()` needed to be called once again after `window.location` is called. It was decided that calling `getAccessToken()` in the else block after `window.location` should be sufficient and thus solves this issue.